# SQL Delete based on condition in join

Tags: sql, join, sql-delete

It is possible to delete records based on a satisfied condition with a join query?

For instance, I have a linking table joining 3 records. The query I have at the moment deletes records from this table where one of the id's isn't `IN()` an imploded Php array. I've come to realise that the query should only remove records from this table if the id's don't exist in the array and they belong to a certain other table based on the a link to another table.

Comment: This is pretty abstract, an example (or the real thing) would be great. Otherwise, I'd fathom you can employ left outer joins and IS NULL for the right side to determine the records to be deleted.

Comment: You can't do DELETE FROM X JOIN Y on X.ID = Y.ID, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I like to use EXISTS clauses for this:

```
DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE
  <<put your array condition here>> 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM TableB Where TableB.ID=TableA.ID)
```

Comment: This is my preferred answer because: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 42):

For SQL Server, the command is slightly different:

```
DELETE FROM TableA
FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Column = TableB.Column 
WHERE TableB.Column IS NULL
```

No, that's not a typo, yes, you **do** need "FROM TableA" **twice**.  At least, you need the second FROM (the first is optional).  The following has the advantage that it works for both SQL Server and MySQL:

```
DELETE TableA
FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Column = TableB.Column 
WHERE TableB.Column IS NULL
```

Comment: The first reference can be an alias, and you can even self join...    
DELETE FROM r2
    FROM #results r
        INNER JOIN #results r2
            ON r2.Field = 'Field1'
               AND r.Value = r2.Value
    WHERE r.Field = 'Field2';

Answer (score 12):

You can use :

**DELETE Based on a Join:**

```
DELETE A      
FROM TableA AS A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB As B ON A.Id = B.TabaleAId 
WHERE B.Column IS NULL
```

**Delete With SubQuery:**

```
DELETE 
FROM TableA AS A
Where
    A.id not in ( Select B.TabaleAId From Tab;eB As B )
```

or

```
DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE Not EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT * 
    FROM TableB As B
    Where B.TableAId = TableA.Id
   )
```

**DELETE Using Table Expressions:**

```
With A 
As
    (
        Select TableA.*
        FROM TableA AS A
            LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB As B ON A.Id = B.TabaleAId 
        WHERE B.Column IS NULL
    )
Delete From A
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DELETE FROM a
  FROM TableA AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS b 
  on a.CALENDAR_DATE = b.CALENDAR_DATE AND a.ID = b.ID 
  Where b.ID is null
```

You can first use the select statement and verify your records that you want to delete and then remove the select statement and add Delete FROM tablename with the above query syntax.

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
WHERE TableB.Column IS NULL
```

Will delete the records in tableA that don't have a corresponding record in TableB.  Is that like what you are after?

Comment: Not sure about other databases but in MySql you definitely will need to do like DELETE TableA FROM TableA LEFT JOIN..

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to Delete based on join is as follow:

1.Write your query using `SELECT` statement instead of `DELETE` statement

```
  SELECT COLUMNS
    FROM    Table1
            INNER JOIN Table2  ON Table1.YYY = Table2.XXX
```

2.Replace `SELECT` COLUMNS with `DELETE  FROM TABLE`

```
 DELETE  FROM Table1
    FROM    Table1
            INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.YYY = Table2.XXX
```

Note that we need to specify `FROM` twice, one for `DELETE` part and one for `JOIN` part.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from TableA
where id in 
(
   select id from TableA
   except select id from TableB
)
```

Which means "delete from tableA where id in table a but not in table b)

Otherwise a Merge statement might help you (when matched/not matched delete etc)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx